# Is there a Whatsapp style webservice API that I can integrate in my app?

Tags: api, rest, messaging

I would not like to spend months re-implementing the technicalities of a WhatsApp style server backend. For this reason I do wonder whether some company has already produced a software that I can use to integrate in my app. The features I would like to be able to do are:

- send messages between user (via App or via webpage)
- allow communication only between users and admin
- manage/view all sent messages from user to admin
- etc..

In short the main criteria is to have a RESTful API that I can use.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

It's not RESTful but [Golgi](http://www.golgi.io) would fullfil most of these criteria. Javascript support has not yet been publicly released though so you may have to wait a few weeks to develop the webpage side of your application.